# flex-wrap is not wrapping elements to next line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have an image gallery built with Lightbox2. Here is the HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="makeup text-center">Galeria</h2>
    <div class="heading-underline"></div>
        <ul class="wrap">
            <a href="img/galeria/1.JPG" data-lightbox="clients" data-title="Opis zdjęcia?">
            <a href=".............................
            <a href="img/galeria/19.JPG" data-lightbox="clients" data-title="Opis zdjęcia?">
                <img src="img/galeria/19.JPG"></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.wrap {
display: inline;
flex-flow: row wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row; }
```

What I'm trying to do is simply move last elements in a row to next line (row) when I shrink browser. Instead of these my photos are just getting smaller and smaller. How can I achieve that?

Comment: how can you apply flex wrap to an inline object?  try making it flex.  But we also need to see the styles for your anchor - if they are percentage widths, then they will obviously always shrink with the browser window

Comment: when I make it flex its getting to single column..

Comment: did you give the wrap a width?

Comment: ok I made width to pixels, then tried display: flex; and everything is perfect now ;) thanks  a  lot

Comment: @MarkR - Glad to know that the issue is resolved. But let me inform you that your code have lots of mistakes. Like <a> tag has not been closed properly. Also you are using <ul> tag without using <li> tag in between that. Request you to correct your code, for better performance.

Comment: i just delete closing tag when i removed 34 lines of almost exactly same code ;) good point about ul, but it doesnt change a thing if it's ul or div...

Comment: using flex properties but not setting the element as display flex is like eating bread and butter without bread

Comment: Without `display: flex` the rest of your CSS is pointless. Also: if you use `flex-flow` you don't need to use `flex-wrap` and `flex-direction`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `display: flex`, When you use `display: inline` all the other flex properties won't affect.

```
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im happy that your problem was solved, but in order to add more help to the question to other contributors, i made a Snippet with the html and the css that can be the answer.

You forgot to put the property:

```
 display: flex
```

on the wrap class.

Also, a couple of errors were found on your html, all of them were solved in the code below

```css
.wrap {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="makeup text-center">Galeria</h2>
    <div class="heading-underline">
        <ul class="wrap">
            <li>
                <a href="https://picsum.photos/200/300" data-lightbox="clients" data-title="Opis zdjęcia?">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></a>
            </li>
           <li>
                <a href="https://picsum.photos/200/300" data-lightbox="clients" data-title="Opis zdjęcia?">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></a>
            </li>
           <li>
                <a href="https://picsum.photos/200/300" data-lightbox="clients" data-title="Opis zdjęcia?">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></a>
            </li>
           <li>
                <a href="https://picsum.photos/200/300" data-lightbox="clients" data-title="Opis zdjęcia?">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></a>
            </li>
           <li>
                <a href="https://picsum.photos/200/300" data-lightbox="clients" data-title="Opis zdjęcia?">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></a>
            </li>
           <li>
                <a href="https://picsum.photos/200/300" data-lightbox="clients" data-title="Opis zdjęcia?">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></a>
            </li>
           <li>
                <a href="https://picsum.photos/200/300" data-lightbox="clients" data-title="Opis zdjęcia?">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></a>
            </li>
           <li>
                <a href="https://picsum.photos/200/300" data-lightbox="clients" data-title="Opis zdjęcia?">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Happy coding